# Weird behavior while iterating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Code

```
const Options = ({ onOptionChange, keys }) => {
  console.log(keys)

  const onRadioChange = (e) => {
    onXAxisChange(e.target.value)
  }

  const onCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(keys)
    for (let key in keys) {
      console.log(key)
      onOptionChange((pre)=>({
        ...pre,
        [key]: e.includes(key)
      }))
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="options">
      <Checkbox.Group className="checkbox" onChange={onCheckboxChange}>
        <Checkbox value="banana"></Checkbox>
        <Checkbox value="apple"></Checkbox>
        <Checkbox value="carrot"></Checkbox>
        <Checkbox value="grape"></Checkbox>
        <Checkbox value="orange"></Checkbox>
      </Checkbox.Group>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How it is called

```
const initialState = {
    banana: false,
    apple: false,
    carrot: false,
    grape: false,
    orage: false
}

const Parent = () => {
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialState);
console.log(selected)

    return (
        <div>
            <Options onOptionChange={setSelected} keys={Object.keys(selected)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The console

```
// At the first render
{banana: false, apple:false, carrot:false, grape: false, orange: false} 
//Parent.console.log(selected)

["banana","apple","carrot","grape","orange"]
// When checkbox clicked
["banana"] // e
["banana","apple","carrot","grape","orange"] //keys
0 // inside the let key in keys loop
1 // suddenly numbers appear!!
2
3
4
{0: false, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, banana: false, apple:false, carrot:false, grape: false, orange: false} //Parent.console.log(selected)
```

I was making checkboxes. In onCheckboxChnage, it is supposed to iterate through keys and if selected set key to true else set false. Before the for loop, keys are what they're expected to be; The keys of Parent.selected. I just checked and `console.log(keys)` inside the loop outputs correct value. But the `key` outputs numbers like index. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop uses `in` which gives you the key rather than the value. In an Array the keys are numbers beginning with zero. You should instead use `of` like this:

```
for (let key of keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Too bad I didn't study js.

There is actually `for..in` and also `for..of` in javascript. The previous is used to iterate over the properties of an object. **It is not and shouldn't be used to iterate over arrays.** Instead **`for..of` is used to iterate over array**.